# post value to html page from menu

Tags: jquery, html

I have a jQuery Multi Level CSS Menu and i want the href value to be posted to the page iframe.html when the user clicks on one of the sub menu, any help would be appreciated.

```
<input type=hidden name=arav value="1234"><ul id='nav'>

<li> <a href='#'>Main menu 1</a>
<ul>
<li style='background-color:#b0c4de;'><a href=getrss.php?q=suna-pol>1submenu 1</a></li>
<li style='background-color:#bebebe;'><a href=getrss.php?q=suna-spo>1submenu 2</a></li>
</ul>
<li> <a href='#'>Main menu 2</a>
<ul>
<li style='background-color:#b0c4de;'><a href=getrss.php?q=arab-me>2submenu 1</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul>



<div class="iframe" >

<iframe name="iframe999" src="iframe.html"  width="100%"  frameborder="0" scrolling="yes" id="iframe" onload='javascript:resizeIframe(this);' />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use it this way: http://jsfiddle.net/6v3dC/

```
$('a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#iframe').attr('src', $(this).attr('href'));
});​
```